# Question about Redis SETNX and handling deadlocks

Tags: redis

I have been reading the official Redis doc on SETNX and its part [*Handling deadlocks*](https://redis.io/commands/setnx#handling-deadlocks) and wanted to ask a question about this part:

"If another client, for instance C5, was faster than C4 and acquired the lock with the GETSET operation, the C4 GETSET operation will return a non expired timestamp. C4 will simply restart from the first step. Note that even if C4 set the key a bit a few seconds in the future this is not a problem."

In this example there are only 2 clients who are contending for a lock, C4 and C5. Let's say that there are more than 2 contenders, C4, C5... all the way to CX. Is there a possibility of C5's lock duration getting stacked to a huge amount (possibly never ending?) if C4 and all other clients arrive all together and extend C5's lock duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the excess lock duration time cannot "stack".

The "few seconds" there is referring to the latency between doing the `GET lock.foo` to see if the key is expired, and doing the `GETSET` to set the new lock time. That's the race condition, that another client will acquire the lock in between those two operations. No matter how many clients there are, if they encounter that race condition they'll only set the time a short amount ahead. If they come later, they will find that the lock is not expired when they do the `GET`, and so they won't try to set it.

This result (that C4 can only change C5's lock timeout by a small amount) does assume that all clients are using the same lock timeout, which is usually the case. If not, then the C4 `GETSET` could overwrite C5's timeout with something drastically different.